# Who or what is Gaea?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-lore

What (if anything) is Gaea in the MTG universe?

I can piece together that she is mainly on Dominaria. Clearly named after the real-life mythical Greek figure. But is she a powerful mage? A planewalkers? A world-soul? a God? Some sort of Queen like figure?

Just basically what is she?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MTG Wiki page about Gaea](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Gaea) summarizes what is known about her. In part, it says this:

> Gaea is a goddess worshiped on Dominaria.
>
> Gaea is believed to be the plane's protector and its creator, and many elves and druids worship her. While never physically appearing, her existence seems to be confirmed by many individuals, and it looks like she assisted directly in protecting Dominaria during the Phyrexian Invasion.